# Printing data with specific key from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

In my React Native app I am trying to print data from my Firebase database which have specific key (passed from another component). I have used similiar code I had used to get all database data but I am getting blank space.

```
var data = []
var currentUser;

class FavPlant extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props)

     this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:(r1,r2) => r1 !==r2})

     this.state = {
         listViewData : data
     }
 }

 componentDidMount(){

  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const keyPlant = navigation.getParam('keyPlant');

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

    if (user != null) {
      var that = this

    firebase.database().ref(user.uid).child('plantList').equalTo('keyPlant').on('child_added',function(data){

        var newData = [...that.state.listViewData]
        newData.push(data)

        that.setState({ listViewData: newData})

    });
  }
})
 }

render(){ return(
<Container>
      <Content>
         <ListView
            enableEmptySections
            dataSource = {this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.listViewData)}
            renderRow={data =>
                <Text>{data.val().bloom}</Text>
            }/>
            </Content>
        </Container>
 )}
```

[image: Database structure]

Comment: Your  `.equalTo('keyPlant')` is a constant String and not your actual variable. You should change it to `.equalTo(keyPlant)`.

Comment: I have removed apostrophes from .equalTo('keyPlant') but I still get no result. When I remove apostrophes from navigation.getParam('keyPlant'); as well I am getting no result and yellow warning: "Posiible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0) Error: Query.equalTo failled: First argument contains undefined property '0kN4FpYslQQfvxJ8ZdWfRCsOZ6P2.plantList'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `DatabaseReference` to the `plantList` element in your JSON:

```
var plantListRef = ...
```

Then you can get the child node with a specific key with:

```
plantListRef.child("-Lg-l2GOOVC_Hni5a3ng").on('value',function(snapshot){
  console.log(snapshot.key); // prints "-Lg-l2GOOVC_Hni5a3ng"
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: I have changed my code to: firebase.database().ref(user.uid).child(keyPlant).on('value', function(snapshot){

            console.log(snapshot.val());
          
        });                                       but I am getting "null" in the console.

Comment: Aren't you missing `plantList` in the path there? `firebase.database().ref(user.uid).child('plantList').child(keyPlant)`? Note that I can't see your exact data structure, so at this point I am guessing.